# Formula execution on multiple intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql

My Data is like this

```
wavelength    reflectance
341.6         2.48
343.6         2.58
344.7         2.37
346.3         2.32
347.9         2.29
349.5         2.36
351.1         2.23
352.6         2.24
354.2         2.25
355.8         2.29
357.4         2.28
358.9         2.23
```

I want to use the formula

- Select the reflectance between the wavelength 340-345 as r
- Select the reflectance between the wavelength 350-355 as i

Formula is

```
r/i
```

- Output of r/i named as tera

Execution

- First reflectance value on both of the selected region as r and i and
  apply formula
- Second, third like this execution

Expected Output

```
tera
1.105655
2.82345
.......
```

Comment: You have posted the same question again. Didn't my answer help you?

Comment: @CrescentMoon, Sir ur answer helps me, but i want to do it like edited question above without sum the values, According to the question the output will be three values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
  r/i as tera,
  (r-i)/(r+i) as tera2
from
    (select wavelength, reflectance as r, row_number() over(order by wavelength) as rn
     from test where wavelength between 340 and 345) t1
    join 
    (select wavelength, reflectance as i, row_number() over(order by wavelength) as rn
     from test where wavelength between 350 and 355) t2 using (rn)
```

It is working fine....

Answer (score 1):

```
select (select sum(reflectance) from table where wavelength between 340 and 345)/
(select sum(reflectance) from table where wavelength between 350 and 355) as tera
```

Comment: so u want reflectance of 340/reflectance of 350 , reflectance of 341/reflectance of 351 ....so on????(should i consider the decimal value???)